# Combine month-wise result set from 2 tables to one result set

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting Monthwise results from 2 tables as 2 different result sets using the below sql

```
    SELECT FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy')  as TestDate,COUNT(_ID) as MATCOUNT
      FROM _tableXX
      where ..........
     group by  FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy')
```

AND

```
     SELECT FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy')  as TestDate,COUNT(_ID) as MATCOUNT
      FROM _tableYY
      where ..........
     group by  FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy')
```

Can we combine these  to a single result set with below columns

```
    TestDate  MATCOUNT   MATCOUNT
```

There is a chance for empty records in one of the tables for few months

```
 First query returns

            June 2017   798 
            July 2017   2   
            May 2017    1189    

     Second one returns


            June 2017   285 
            May 2017    111 

     Trying to build the result set as


            June 2017   798  285
            July 2017   2    0
            May 2017    1189 111
```

Comment: add a few sample rows with desired output please.

Answer (score 1):

```
with c1 as ( 
    SELECT FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy')  as TestDate,COUNT(_ID) as MATCOUNT
  FROM _tableXX
  where ..........
 group by  FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy')
),
c2 as (
       SELECT FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy')  as TestDate,COUNT(_ID) as MATCOUNT
  FROM _tableYY
  where ..........
 group by  FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy')
)

select coalesce(c1.testdate, c2.testdate) as TestDate, c1.MATCOUNT, c2.MATCOUNT
FROM c1 FULL OUTER JOIN c2 on c1.testDate=c2.testDate
```

If a row is missing in either table the appropriate MATCOUNT will be null, you can replace the select statement with

```
select coalesce(c1.testdate, c2.testdate) as TestDate, 
       coalesce(c1.MATCOUNT,0) as MATCOUNT,
       coalesce(c2.MATCOUNT,0) as MATCOUNT
```

To get zeros instead

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a full outer join between your tables and using coalesce where rows exhibit `NULL`: Run the below sample:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp1 ( TestDate NVARCHAR(20), MATCOUNT INT )
CREATE TABLE #temp2 ( TestDate NVARCHAR(20), MATCOUNT INT ) 

INSERT INTO #temp1 ( TestDate, MATCOUNT )
VALUES ( N'Jan 2017', 10  ),
       ( N'Feb 2017', 20  ),
       ( N'Mar 2017', 30  )

INSERT INTO #temp2 ( TestDate, MATCOUNT )
VALUES ( N'Jan 2017', 5  ), 
       ( N'Mar 2017', 15  ),
       ( N'Apr 2017', 25  )

SELECT COALESCE(t.TestDate, t2.TestDate) AS TestDate,
       COALESCE(t.MATCOUNT, 0) AS MatCount1,
       COALESCE(t2.MATCOUNT, 0) AS MatCount2
FROM #temp1 AS t
    FULL OUTER JOIN #temp2 AS t2
        ON t2.TestDate = t.TestDate;

DROP TABLE #temp1
DROP TABLE #temp2
```

Produces:

```
TestDate    MatCount1   MatCount2
Jan 2017    10          5
Feb 2017    20          0
Mar 2017    30          15
Apr 2017    0           25
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select TestDate,sum(matcount1) matcount1,sum(matcount2) matcount2
        from 
        (
        SELECT FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy')  as TestDate,COUNT(_ID) as MATCOUNT1,0 as MATCOUNT2
                   FROM _tableXX
                   where ..........
            group by  FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy')
        Union    
        SELECT FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy')  as TestDate,0 as MATCOUNT1,COUNT(_ID) as MATCOUNT2
                   FROM _tableYY
                   where ..........
            group by  FORMAT(CompletedDate,'MMMM yyyy') ) a
 group by TestDate
```

Comment: UNION will cause repetition of rows . Please see example result set in question